# Determine the order of the local truncation error (LTE) of a numerical integration method

Tags: numerical-methods

Given $y(t)$ the initial-valu problem:
$y'=f(t,y),$    $y(0)=y_0$

I need to find the order of the local truncation error for the following numerical integration method:

$w_{n+1}=w_n+hf(t_n+\alpha h,w_n+\alpha hf(t_n,w_n)), \alpha ∈ [0,1]$

I know I have to assume $w_n=w(t_n)$, and then Taylor expand the exact value $y(t_{n+1})$ and everything that isn't $w(t_n)$ in the right hand side and then calculate the difference. I get stuck at Taylor expanding the right hand side. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Following the great book by Vuik, Vermolen, van Gijzen and Vuik(Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations).

We are interested in the local truncation error
\begin{equation}
\tau_{n+1} := \frac{y_{n+1}-w_{n+1}}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}, where $y_n$ is the exact solution and $w_n$ the approximation at $t_n$. (I take $h=\Delta t$). 
Then for "simple" methods you can take the Taylor series of $y_{n+1}$ at $t_n$ and plug in the method for $w_{n+1}$. In this case the $f(\cdot,f(\cdot,\cdot))$ part complicates the story. Again, Taylor expansion will help! Take the expansion about $(t_n,y_n)$ and see that we can write:
\begin{align}
f(\bar{t},\bar{w}) &= f(t_n+\alpha\Delta t, w_n+\alpha \Delta t f(t_n, w_n))\\
& =f(t_n,y_n) + (t_n + \alpha \Delta t -t_n) \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + (y_n+\alpha \Delta t f(t_n,y_n)-y_n)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)\\
&= f_n + \alpha \Delta t \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + f_n \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2) \implies \\
&w_{n+1} = y_n + \Delta t f_n + \alpha \Delta t^2 \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + f_n \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3)
\end{align}
Then by the chain-rule we can continue and write
\begin{align}
&y''_n =\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}y_n' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + f_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \implies\\
&w_{n+1} = y_n + \Delta t y'_n + \alpha \Delta t^2 y''_n + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3).
\end{align}
However, the Taylor series of $y_{n+1}$ at $t_n$ can be written as
\begin{align}
y_{n+1} = y_n + \Delta t y'_n + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2y''_n + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3). 
\end{align}
From there you see that the selection of $\alpha$ determines your local truncation error being either $\mathcal{O}(\Delta t)$ or $\mathcal{O}(\Delta t^2)$.